# Помогите составить регулярное выражение убрать лишний символ

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

ребят помогите составить регулярное выражение.

Есть число 12.3. Нужно после тройки убрать точку. То есть что бы осталась только точка между двойкой и тройкой.

На данный момент регулярка выглядит так: /[^0-9.]/ из определенного текста у меня вырезается все кроме цифр и точек. Но проблема в том что в конце стоит точка, ее то мне как раз и нужно убрать.

Comment: Всегда прикладывайте входные данные и результат. Как я понял вам нужно `12.3` -> `123`?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/xVKCQE/6

Comment: не работает, текст не вырезаем, да и пустое окно у меня выдает(((  $txt = preg_replace('(\d\.\d+)\.','',$txt);

Comment: В общем спасибо ребят, так и не разобрался с регулярками. Сделал через substr

Answer (score 2):

Вам необходимо  найти число, а не удалять последовательности или символы, отличные от числа:

```
if (preg_match('~\d+(?:\.\d+)?~', $s, $m)) {
    echo $m[0];
}
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/nMQPyi/2).

[PHP-демо](https://ideone.com/fPgHSx):

```
$s = "..d.....12.3..d.e!";
if (preg_match('~\d+(?:\.\d+)?~', $s, $m)) {
    echo $m[0];
} // => 12.3
```

**Подробности**

- `\d+`  - 1 и более цифр
- `(?:` - начало незахватывающей подмаски, которая находит

  - `\.` - точку, а затем
  - `\d+` - 1 и более цифр
- `)?` - один или ноль повторений.

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас `12.3.` это полная строка, то можете использовать указатель на конец строки `$`:

```
/\.+$/
```

Замену делаете на пустую строку -> все точки на конце строки будут удалены.

P.S. А еще есть функция `trim()` для удаление символов с краев строки и в ней можно указать удаляемые символы.